# How to apply cufon js to only IE in template.php

Tags: drupal

I have some font problem in IE ,so I am trying to apply font-family through js,Its work but js is applied in all browser.How to apply js to only IE.This my code

```
drupal_add_js('sites/all/themes/blogbuzz/js/cufon-yui.js');
drupal_add_js('sites/all/themes/blogbuzz/js/Helvetica_CE_35_Thin_100.font.js');
drupal_add_js('(function ($){
$(document).ready(function()
{

       Cufon.replace("#content-header");
       Cufon.replace("#client_tle");
       Cufon.replace("#block-block-16");            



});
})(jQuery)', "inline");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $.browser.msie variable of jQuery.
Remember to use that with jQuery Migrate if you are using jQuery 1.9+.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   if($.browser.msie){
          Cufon.replace("#content-header");
          Cufon.replace("#client_tle");
          Cufon.replace("#block-block-16");  
   }
});
```

Regards.